# My SQL: Sum each row After Specific Row

Tags: mysql

I have a table which collects the results of football games played every week.

Based on the results of each game I input 3, 1 or 0 points for a player by ID, depending one whether they have won, drawn, or lost.

```
id  Name    A1  B1  C1  A2  B2  C2

1   C       0   3   1   3   0   0

2   G       3   0   1   3   0   0

3   k       3   0   1   0   3   3

4   S       3   0   1   N   N   N

5   G       N   N   N   3   0   0

6   D       N   N   N   N   N   N
```

I'd like to be able to sum these columns, and I can do it manually by using `SELECT SUM(A1+B1+C1+A2+B2+C2) FROM Results WHERE id ='1'`

My issue is that each week I add an additional 2 or 3 game results - so I'd need to manually add the new games into SUM().

I thought that I would be able to use something like `SUM(...) AFTER Name WHERE id = 'id'`

I'm hoping I can concatenate the names of all Columns after Name and then add that into SUM(concatenatedcolumns).

But I haven't found a good example to work from yet.

Comment: Apologies, I can't get the table to display correctly.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? mysql is not the same thing as sql server.

Comment: Also, `N` are null values.

Comment: First figure out what RDBMS you're using. Then reconsider your design (if this is your design). A database table is NOT a spreadsheet. Oh, and welcome to SO.

Comment: Oh I see the problem you are facing. The problem is your design. You should have a new row for each new game, not a new column. You need to read up on normalization.

Comment: My error, it's MySQL on Ubuntu

Comment: So I should have columns for players and rows for games.

Comment: Should I then store unique ID's for players in a separate table?

Comment: Not exactly. You should have a table for games, another table for players and a third table for tracking which players participated in each game. This is a many to many relationship between players and games. That is to say that 1 game can have many players and 1 player can have many games.

Comment: Well, typically games have teams, and teams have players - but maybe your setup is different.

Comment: @Strawberry I would assume the team information would be in yet another table of course but the reference would be in the game table.

Comment: Ok thanks, so my next step is figure out how the relationship between these two items is managed.

Comment: @denski i suppose so, but it's just possible that someone has attempted to compile statistics about football games and players before - and that they may have had the presence of mind to share their experience.

Comment: @Strawberry, Absolutely, but it's more fun to self create. Thanks for the welcome.

Comment: Sure, but one need not do it an a vacuum. And *we* are not *you*!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have two tables if you do not care about 'games' metadata, I assume not as you were ready to have games listed as columns.

```
table:players (rows unique by id)
id name
1  A
2  B

table:scores (rows unique by combination of game_id and player_id)
game_id, player_id, score
A1       1          3
A1       2          1
B1       1          0
```

You can then join these two tables to get sum of scores for each players across all games

```
select players.id, players.name, sum(scores.score) from players inner join score
on players.id = scores.player_id group by players.id, players.name
```

There will not be any rows for players who did not appear in a game in 'scores' table and you do not have to deal with any null values thereby.

Comment: This is very useful, thanks stk. I think in particular what is helpful is the absence of null values as one of the calculations I'll make is (points/games played). I think for my own learning I'll try and do it 1) This way and 2) as Sean Lange suggested using 3 different tables.